# What would be the easiest way to parse hg log output and present it in a different

Tags: python, mercurial

What would be the easiest way to parse some of `hg log`'s output (with some extra options) and present it in a differently sorted way with colour on windows cmd?

I know of graphlog and hgview (which I've never been able to get running on windows) and alike, but they all have their little quirks and in the way, I never get what I want with them.

For example, I want logs to look something like (the upper part). It would be preferable if it could be done with python, since I would like to avoid installing perl as well, but if it can't ... :/

**Anyone?**

[image]

Comment: So a graphlog like the one described in http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2010-01-15-styling-mercurials-cli/#short-graphlog  and https://bitbucket.org/sjl/mercurial-cli-templates/src/c060c94622e9/map-cmdline.sglog isn't enough?

Comment: How is this not constructive?

Comment: @VonC - Something like that, yeah. Only stevelosh has that working on unix shell, and on cmd it gives out a bit weird results. Take that map-cmdline.slog file and explain what it does (expecially the \33[0;35 ... parts) and I'll accept it.

Comment: I have explained those codes in my answer, but that means a bit of work is still involved to adapt this solution to a Unix environment.

Comment: @VonC - Surely, you mean the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

Without any script, you can find a way to use graphlog with colors to achieve a result similar to your illustration:

See [Short Graphlog](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2010-01-15-styling-mercurials-cli/#short-graphlog):

[image: colors with graphlog]

It is based on an alias [defined in here](https://bitbucket.org/sjl/mercurial-cli-templates/src/c060c94622e9/map-cmdline.sglog), however it uses special code for coloring a *bash* (Windows) shell. So you might need to adapt those special codes with some adapted for a cmd DOS shell, using **[ANSI escape codes for Windows](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php)**.

Comment: No, I am on Dos (it's not DOS, but cmd ... but never mind that). SteveLosh is on bash/zsh/whatever in this particular case.